# How do sklearn StandardScaler works inside a Pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

I'm trying to make my first machine learning exercise with the [Pima Diabetes](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kumargh/pimaindiansdiabetescsv) dataset.
I tried to use KNN model two times, one manually, and another inside a Pipeline. There is the results:

**Just getting the samples and the labels**

```py
X_train = np.asarray(train.iloc[:, :8])
X_test = np.asarray(test.iloc[:, :8])
y_train = np.asarray(train['Outcome'])
y_test = np.asarray(test['Outcome'])
```

**Without Pipeline**

```
scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

mod = KNeighborsClassifier()

mod.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

*Results:*

> Precision =  0.4835164835164835

> Recall =  0.8979591836734694

> F1 =  0.6285714285714287

> Accuracy =  0.48

**With Pipeline**

```
mod = Pipeline([
                ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                ('model', KNeighborsClassifier())
])

mod.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

*Results:*

> Precision =  0.5517241379310345

> Recall =  0.6530612244897959

> F1 =  0.5981308411214952

> Accuracy =  0.57

Why are the results going different? That's how I print the results:

```
y_pred = mod.predict(X_test)

print('Precision = ', precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
print('Recall = ', recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
print('F1 = ', f1_score(y_test, y_pred))
print('Accuracy = ', mod.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Without the pipeline, how do you get the results?

Comment: The exactly same way

Comment: You need to scale the test data (using `transform` and not `fit_transform`) first.

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger, that worked. Seems that, just like the first result show us, without the test data transformed it gives a better recall result. Is that a "fake" result?